# facebook registration plugin form's target problem

Tags: facebook-graph-api, modal-dialog

I am using facebook registration plugin .
(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/)

I need to use it in a modal box or in an iframe.

but there is a problem about its form target.
form sends data to "_top" frame.

How can I change it to "_self" or "mytargetname"

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with facebook registration plugin.

Refer this link : http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15062

Comment: This seems helpful, but link only answers are removed quickly because they lose all context when links break. Please move some information from the bug (perhaps how to reproduce it?) into the answer.